# NavTreeBuilder in preview mode

Tags: crafter-cms

I was wondering if Crafter engine in preview mode changes how NavTreeBuilder behaves.

I have observed that the exact same call to `navTreeBuilder.getNavTree(url, 2, ...)` is taking above 5s to respond in preview whereas less than a second in regular crafter delivery nodes.

This has been observed in all environments we manage with the exact same speed behavior. To be precise, this is crafter 2.5.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 4):

Preview and Engine run exactly the same code.  The only difference is that Preview does not cache descriptors.

You can prove that caching what is improving the performance by trying in the (non-production) delivery environment immediately after a restart.

If that proves out then the question is:
* How large is the tree you are walking (breadth and depth [looks like depth 2])
* What filters are you applying

5s is an unusually long time.  I expect either: an enormous amount of objects, complex filters or some complicating environmental factor to be the culprit.